# bold and normal font rendering

Tags: list, fonts, highlight, bold

It is observed in some fonts sat Verdana, that the rendering for bold and normal text does not occupy the same width for a given text.
In my application i am making use of one such font ,and there is UI with list and highlighted item.
for highlighted item the font is same with bold attribute ,because of above mentioned font issue the text appears to move(enlarge and occupy more space )horizontally when the list is scrolled.
I can use bold font with one less in font size which seem ok but not perfect
Is there any corrective measure to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the default attribute of most proportional fonts. If having the string width increased seems ugly, try using other visual methods to draw attention to the selected item, such as changing the background color.

Comment: I cannot modify the requirement.:(

Answer (score 0):

You could make the list items wide enough to accommodate size increase when it becomes bold.

If the highlight has to be bold, most likely your only option is using a proportional font (doesn't need to be courier, you may find some sans-serif proportional fonts acceptable).

Comment: Garus here the question is not whether text fits into boundary ,the thing is the text appears to enlarge when it gets the highlight. Let me edit the question to clarify it